# Python3 My Code Doesn't want input again

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
asd = 1
limit = "+-*/1234567890 "

while asd:
    data = input("YOUR PROCESS? ")
    for i in data:

        if i not in limit:
            print("?? ERROR ?? ")
            quit()

        else:
            print(eval(data))

            again = input("AGAIN? (E/H)")

            if again == "E":
                pass

            else:
                 print("GOOD BYE... \n")
                 asd = 0
```

When I execute this code after one process, it doesn't want new value for "data". Running with first data value. How can i solve this?

Comment: What sort of input is to be expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is running this for each character in the input:

```
        print(eval(data))

        again = input("AGAIN? (E/H)")

        if again == "E":
            pass

        else:
             print("GOOD BYE... \n")
             asd = 0
```

try getting rid of the else that it is in, and putting the above block right in the while loop (after the for loop not in it)